# Python - Urllib2 Wait for page to load to scrape data

Tags: python, redirect, web-scraping, load, captcha

Firstly, I'd like to say that I do not want to use any libraries that are not provided with Python 2.7.10. The same question was posted on Stack Overflow but was answered with the Requests library.

I have a script that logs into Roblox.com using urllib2. To check if there is a captcha before I try to log in, I wanted to do `check_captcha = re.findall('recaptcha_image', newlogin)` but roblox needs to redirect to the captcha login page AND the captcha has to load onto the page.

So how can I make Python wait to redirect/load the page fully before I go ahead and `.read()` and scrape it.

Comment: you can try `time.sleep(10)` that might work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will wait 10 seconds before it reads it:

```
import urllib2
import time
url = 'Roblox url'
data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
time.sleep(10)
data = data.read()
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I found out that Roblox prints `We need to make sure you're not a robot! To sign in, please type the words in the picture.` so I instead did `re.findall('robot', newlogin)` instead of waiting for the captcha to load.