# How to get python requests or urllib2 to wait for final page

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using python requests and beautifulsoup to verify a html document. However, the server for the landing page has some backend code that delays several seconds before presenting the final html document. I've tried the `redirect=true` approach but I end up with the original document. When loading the url on a browser, there is a 2-3 second delay while the page is created by the server. I've tried various samples like `url2.geturl()` after page load but all of these return the original url (and do so well before the 2-3 seconds elapses). I need something that emulates a browser and grabs the final document.

Btw, I am able to view the correct DOM elements in Chrome, just not problematically in python.

Comment: How does the content load in the browser? AJAX?

Comment: Would it suffice with a sleep as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31310321/python-urllib2-wait-for-page-to-load-to-scrape-data) ?

Comment: The backend code is running Angular and JavaScript.

Comment: I assume this method does not work with dynamically generated pages. I found this article: http://stanford.edu/~mgorkove/cgi-bin/rpython_tutorials/Scraping_a_Webpage_Rendered_by_Javascript_Using_Python.php

Comment: Using a secondary binary seems to be a heavy lift for my application.

Comment: I've had this problem before. Is the URL public? If so, what is it?

Comment: It's not a public url. It is a hardware device that has internal web server and content. It appears the common solution is to use selenium which drives an actual web browser, which may be the (albeit hacky) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out after a few cycles. This requires a combination of 2 solutions (use python selenium package and time.sleep). Sets the background chrome process to run headless, get the url, wait for server side code to complete, then load the document. Here, I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse the DOM.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

def run():

    url = "http://192.168.1.55"
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('headless')
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    browser.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
    data = bs.find_all('h3')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```